Want to use COALESCE on related fields on django model
I have model structure as below.
from django.db import models

class Switch(models.Model):
    fqdn = models.CharField(unique=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Switch'

class Colo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Colo'

class Clstr(models.Model):
    colo = models.ForeignKey('Colo',
                             db_column='colo',
                             related_name='clstrs')
    name = models.CharField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Clstr'

class ESwtch(models.Model):
    switch = models.OneToOneField(Switch,
                                  db_column='switch',
                                  primary_key=True,
                                  related_name='e_swtch')
    clstr = models.ForeignKey('Clstr',
                                db_column='Clstr',
                                related_name="e_swtches")

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'ESwtch'


class BSwtch(models.Model):
    switch = models.OneToOneField(Switch,
                                  db_column='switch',
                                  primary_key=True,
                                  related_name='b_swtch')
    clstr = models.ForeignKey('Clstr',
                                db_column='clstr',
                                related_name='b_swtches')
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'BSwtch'


class VChas(models.Model):
    clstr = models.ForeignKey('Clstr',
                              db_column='clstr',
                              related_name='v_chas')
    vc_num = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'VChas'

class VSwtch(models.Model):
    switch = models.OneToOneField(Switch,
                                  db_column='switch',
                                  primary_key=True,
                                  related_name='v_swtch')
    v_chas = models.ForeignKey(VChas,
                                        db_column='v_chas',
                                        related_name='v_switches')
    role = models.CharField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'VSwtch'


class CTrig(models.Model):
    switch = models.ForeignKey(Switch,
                               db_column='switch',
                               related_name='c_trig')
    config_trigger = models.CharField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'CTrig'

I want to get the CTrig based on Colo.name. I ran raw query as below.
SELECT `CTrig`.`switch`,
       `CTrig`.`config_trigger`,
       `Switch`.`fqdn`
FROM `CTrig`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `Switch` ON (`CTrig`.`switch` = `Switch`.`id`)
LEFT OUTER JOIN `BSwtch` ON (`Switch`.`id` = `BSwtch`.`switch`)
LEFT OUTER JOIN `ESwtch` ON (`Switch`.`id` = `ESwtch`.`switch`)
LEFT OUTER JOIN `VSwtch` ON (`Switch`.`id` = `VSwtch`.`switch`)
LEFT OUTER JOIN `VChas` ON (`VSwtch`.`v_chas` = `VChas`.`id`)
LEFT OUTER JOIN `Cluster` ON (COALESCE(`BSwtch`.`clstr`,
                                       `VChas`.`clstr`,
                                       `ESwtch`.`clstr`) = `Clstr`.`id`)
LEFT OUTER JOIN `Colo` ON (`Clstr`.`colo` = `Colo`.`id`)
WHERE `Colo`.`name` = 'coloname'
ORDER BY `ConfigTrigger`.`triggered_at` DESC
LIMIT 1;

This query works fine, but when I try to implement this using DJango model, its giving error.
I tried as below.
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce
...
...
CTrig.objects.select_related("switch").filter(
    Coalesce("switch__b_swtch__clstr__colo__name",
             "switch__e_swtch__clstr__colo__name",                          
             "switch__v_swtch__v_chas__clstr__colo__name")=="coloname")
...
...

But this gives error, as below.
File "/home/user/var/virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg/mod/api/views/ctrig.py", line 49, in get_queryset
    ret_val = ret_val.filter(
  File "/home/user/var/virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 941, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/user/var/virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 961, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone._filter_or_exclude_inplace(negate, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/user/var/virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 968, in _filter_or_exclude_inplace
    self._query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/user/var/virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1391, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "/home/user/var/virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1410, in _add_q
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(
  File "/home/user/var/virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1281, in build_filter
    arg, value = filter_expr
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable bool object

coalesce is not able to convert the leftside related fields. Doc for the coalesce give example where this function used on left right side of the equal operator.

What does the traceback say?

@LordElrond I updated question with traceback.
